# Optimizing a SQL query to remove a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, optimization

I am trying to write a query that will go through a table and apply any credits that are on an account to the oldest balance. I could not figure out a way to do this without using a cursor, and I know cursors should be avoided at all costs if possible, so I am coming here for help.

```
select * into #balances from [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] where amount > 0
select * into #credits from [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] where amount < 0

create index ba_ID on #balances (CLIENT_ID)
create index cr_ID on #credits (CLIENT_ID)

declare credit_cursor cursor for
select [CLIENT_ID], amount, cvtGUID from #credits

open credit_cursor
declare @client_id varchar(11)
declare @credit money
declare @balance money
declare @cvtGuidBalance uniqueidentifier
declare @cvtGuidCredit uniqueidentifier
fetch next from credit_cursor into @client_id, @credit, @cvtGuidCredit
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
      while(@credit < 0 and (select count(*) from #balances where @client_id = CLIENT_ID and amount <> 0) > 0)
      begin
            select top 1  @balance = amount, @cvtGuidBalance = cvtGuid from #balances where @client_id = CLIENT_ID and amount <> 0 order by AGING_DATE
            set @credit = @balance + @credit
            if(@credit > 0)
            begin
                  update #balances set amount = @credit where cvtGuid = @cvtGuidBalance
                  set @credit = 0
            end
            else
            begin
                  update #balances set amount = 0 where cvtGuid = @cvtGuidBalance
            end
      end
      update #credits set amount = @credit where cvtGuid = @cvtGuidCredit
      fetch next from credit_cursor into @client_id, @credit, @cvtGuidCredit
end

close credit_cursor
deallocate credit_cursor

delete #balances where AMOUNT = 0
delete #credits where AMOUNT = 0

truncate table [IDAT_AR_BALANCES]

insert [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] select * from #balances
insert [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] select * from #credits

drop table #balances
drop table #credits
```

In my test cases for 10000 records and 1000 clients it take 26 seconds to run, by adding the two indexes on CLIENT_ID I was able to bring down the number to 14 seconds. However this is still too slow for what I need, the final result could have as many as 10000 clients and over 4,000,000 records so the run time could easily become in the double digit minutes.

Any recommendations on how I can restructure this to remove the cursor would be greatly appreciated.

Example (**updated to show that you could have multiple credits after it has been run**):

```
before
cvtGuid      client_id      ammount     AGING_DATE
xxxxxx       1              20.00       1/1/2011
xxxxxx       1              30.00       1/2/2011
xxxxxx       1              -10.00      1/3/2011
xxxxxx       1              5.00        1/4/2011
xxxxxx       2              20.00       1/1/2011
xxxxxx       2              15.00       1/2/2011
xxxxxx       2              -40.00      1/3/2011
xxxxxx       2              5.00        1/4/2011
xxxxxx       3              10.00       1/1/2011
xxxxxx       3              -20.00      1/2/2011
xxxxxx       3              5.00        1/3/2011
xxxxxx       3              -8.00       1/4/2011

after
cvtGuid      client_id      ammount     AGING_DATE
xxxxxx       1              10.00       1/1/2011
xxxxxx       1              30.00       1/2/2011
xxxxxx       1              5.00        1/4/2011
xxxxxx       3              -5.00       1/2/2011
xxxxxx       3              -8.00       1/4/2011
```

so it will apply the negative credit to the oldest positive balance (*client 1 in the example*), if there are no remaining positive balances after it is done it leaves the remaining negative (*client 3*), if they perfectly cancel out (this is the case 90% of the time with the real data) it will totally remove the record (*client 2*).

Comment: Can you give some example before/after data so we don't have to try and figure out what your cursor is doing first before we can answer?

Comment: Is it possible there are multiple negative balances for the same `client_id` ?

Comment: @ypercube yes there can be more than one.

Comment: @Scott - shouldn't date for client_id 3 be 1/3/2011 io 1/2/2011? If it's 1/2/2011, I don't get the rationale.

Comment: @Lieven it is because the credit has a date of 1/2/2011 and only 15 of it's 20 was used, so you still have a 5 dollar credit from 1/2/2011 on your account.

Comment: @Scott - that rules out my answer. My answer picks 1/3/2011 for client_id 3 as remaining record with the -5.00 amount.

Comment: I believe, once you've got only credit records for an account, any newcoming positive ammounts should do to them just what the negative ones had done to the prior positives, shouldn't they. I mean, they should eliminate/increase (i.e. bring nearer to 0) the negative values. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to solve this with the help of a recursive CTE.

The basic idea is this:

1. Get the totals of positive and negative values separately for every account (`client_id`).
2. Iterate over every account and 'pinch off' an amount of one of the two totals, depending on `amount`'s sign and absolute value (i.e. never 'pinch off' of the corresponding total more than its current value). The same value should be added to/subtracted from `amount`.
3. After update, delete those rows where `amount` has become 0.

For my solution I've borrowed Lieven's table variable definition (thank you!), adding one column (`cvtGuid`, declared as `int` for the purpose of the demonstration) and one row (the last one from the original example, which was missing from Lieven's script).

```
/* preparing the demonstration data */
DECLARE @IDAT_AR_BALANCES TABLE (
  cvtGuid int IDENTITY,
  client_id INTEGER
  , amount FLOAT
  , date DATE
);
INSERT INTO @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  SELECT 1, 20.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 30.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, -10.00, '1/3/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 5.00, '1/4/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 15.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, -40.00, '1/3/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 5.00, '1/4/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 10.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, -20.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5.00, '1/3/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, -8.00, '1/4/2011';

/* checking the original contents */
SELECT * FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES;

/* getting on with the job: */
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT
    /* 1) preparing the totals */
    client_id,
    total_pos = SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END),
    total_neg = SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END)
  FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  GROUP BY client_id
),
refined AS (
  /* 2) refining the original data with auxiliary columns:
     * rownum - row numbers (unique within accounts);
     * amount_to_discard_pos - the amount to discard `amount` completely if it's negative;
     * amount_to_discard_neg - the amount to discard `amount` completely if it's positive
  */
  SELECT
    *,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date),
    amount_to_discard_pos = CAST(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN -amount ELSE 0 END AS float),
    amount_to_discard_neg = CAST(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN -amount ELSE 0 END AS float)
  FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
),
prepared AS (
  /* 3) preparing the final table (using a recursive CTE) */
  SELECT
    cvtGuid = CAST(NULL AS int),
    client_id,
    amount = CAST(NULL AS float),
    date = CAST(NULL AS date),
    amount_update = CAST(NULL AS float),
    running_balance_pos = total_pos,
    running_balance_neg = total_neg,
    rownum = CAST(0 AS bigint)
  FROM totals
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    n.cvtGuid,
    n.client_id,
    n.amount,
    n.date,
    amount_update = CAST(
      CASE
        WHEN n.amount_to_discard_pos < p.running_balance_pos
        THEN n.amount_to_discard_pos
        ELSE p.running_balance_pos
      END
      +
      CASE
        WHEN n.amount_to_discard_neg > p.running_balance_neg
        THEN n.amount_to_discard_neg
        ELSE p.running_balance_neg
      END
    AS float),
    running_balance_pos = CAST(p.running_balance_pos -
      CASE
        WHEN n.amount_to_discard_pos < p.running_balance_pos
        THEN n.amount_to_discard_pos
        ELSE p.running_balance_pos
      END
    AS float),
    running_balance_neg = CAST(p.running_balance_neg -
      CASE
        WHEN n.amount_to_discard_neg > p.running_balance_neg
        THEN n.amount_to_discard_neg
        ELSE p.running_balance_neg
      END
    AS float),
    n.rownum
  FROM refined n
    INNER JOIN prepared p ON n.client_id = p.client_id AND n.rownum = p.rownum + 1
)
/*                  -- some junk that I've forgotten to clean up,
SELECT *            -- which you might actually want to use
FROM prepared       -- to view the final prepared result set
WHERE rownum > 0    -- before actually running the update
ORDER BY client_id, rownum
*/
/* performing the update */
UPDATE t
SET amount = t.amount + u.amount_update
FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES t INNER JOIN prepared u ON t.cvtGuid = u.cvtGuid
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

/* checking the contents after UPDATE */
SELECT * FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES;

/* deleting the eliminated amounts */
DELETE FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES WHERE amount = 0;

/* checking the contents after DELETE */
SELECT * FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES;
```

---

**UPDATE**

As Lieven has correctly suggested (thank you again!), you can delete all the rows from the accounts where `amount` adds up to 0 first, *then* update the other rows. That will increase the overall performance, since, as you say, the majority of the data have their amounts adding up to 0.

Here's a variation on Lieven's solution for deleting 'zero accounts':

```
DELETE FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
WHERE client_id IN (
  SELECT client_id
  FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  GROUP BY client_id
  HAVING SUM(amount) = 0
)
```

Keep in mind, though, that the `DELETE` after the update will still be needed too, because the update may reset some of the `amount` values to 0. If I were you, I might consider creating a trigger FOR UPDATE that would automatically delete the rows where `amount = 0`. Such a solution is not always acceptable, but sometimes is fine. It depends on what else you can possibly do with your data. It may also depend on whether it's solely your project or there are other maintainers as well (who don't like rows 'magically' and unexpectedly disappearing).

Comment: +1. This returns exactly what OP requests. You might want to delete everything that adds up to 0 *before* juggling with the rest to improve performance. OP stated that 90% of the records would get deleted anyway.

Comment: I love your solution but in my actual table I can not have nulls in the amount column (or anywhere for that matter). What do I need to change to still be able to use your code? worst case I can add a new column that allows nulls and copy the values over.

Comment: @Scott- what does a NULL represent? 0 or something else? *You can use COALESCE or ISNULL everywhere an amount column is used*

Comment: @Lieven, I am not 100% sure what the code is doing, (recursive CTE's are new to me) but I think is is bombing right after the **3)** comment

Comment: The exact error is `Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AMOUNT', table 'test.dbo.IDAT_AR_BALANCES'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.` Line 9 is the `WITH totals AS (` line

Comment: @Scott - You probably have to change `SET amount = t.amount + u.amount_update` to `SET amount = COALESCE(t.amount, 0) + COALESCE(u.amount_update, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I need to run some tests with some real world data but if it is faster I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ran it on some real world data (totals are after the 0 summed clients are removed) with 313 clients, 15690 balances, 19012 credits. I get the error `Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: @Scott: Sorry for being silent. 1. The script works with the example data. 2. It doesn't update `amount` with NULLs. (Again, not in the example data.) 3. I'm not saying that I'm right and you are wrong. I may simply be missing some important details, which, once introduced to me, I would gladly take into account.

Comment: I fixed the null issue, the coalesce works fine. the main problem is is using real world data instead of a small testbed causes more than 100 recursions.

Comment: @Scott: Can `cvtGuid` be NULL by any chance?

Comment: no, it is a unique identifier that also is the primary key, however just coleleasing the amount totals fixed the issue and it runs fine, it is just the max recursion depth that is the issue.

Comment: @Scott: Added `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the UPDATE statement, which means unlimited recursion. You can replace 0 with a positive integer up to 32767 which means that maximum level of recursion. (The default, as you may have guessed, is 100.)

Comment: @Scott - one last thing as I'm dying to know... what is the performance difference?

Comment: @Lieven Actually, to be honest, my indexed cursor was faster, and adding your delete sum 0 records brought the run time to about 2 and 1/2 min which is accept

Comment: @Scott - so you have gained nothing? 14 sec to 2,5 minutes?

Comment: @Scott: A bitter, but valuable truth. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Lieven, 14 secconds was with small subset of test data, live data with the original script was 1 hour. so its 1 hour down to 2.5 min.

Answer (score 2):

I put together something very similar recently.  I didn't find a really simple solution, it ended up requiring a couple hundred lines, but I can offer a couple of points.

You can put your credits into a table with a serial number for each client:

```
CREATE TABLE #CreditsInSequence
  (
  Client_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Sequence  INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, Sequence),
  Date      DATE NOT NULL,
  Amount    DECIMAL NOT NULL
  )
INSERT INTO #CreditsInSequence (Client_ID, Sequence, Date, Amount)
  SELECT
    client_id, ROW_NUMBER (PARTITION BY client_id, ORDER BY date) AS Sequence, date, amount
  FROM
    #credits
```

If a client has just one credit, they'll have one row in the table, with Sequence = 1.  If another client has three credits, they will have three rows, with sequence numbers 1, 2, and 3.  You can now loop through this temp table, and you'll only need a number of iterations equal to the most credits that any single client has.

```
DECLARE @MaxSeq INT = (SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM #Credits)
DECLARE @Seq    INT = 1
WHILE @Seq <= @MaxSeq
  BEGIN
  -- Do something with this set of credits
  SELECT
    Client_ID, Date, Amount
  FROM
    #CreditsInSequence
  WHERE
    Sequence = @Seq

  SET @Seq += 1  -- Don't forget to increment the loop!
  END
```

Just as with your cursor, this lets you operate sequentially, fully handling the first credit for each client before moving on to the second.  As a bonus, in my experience this kind of "pretend FOR loop" is often faster than a cursor.

To identify the right balance to which to apply each credit, I'd start with something like this:

```
SELECT
  B.client_id,
  MIN(B.date) AS Date,
  B.amount - COALESCE(AC.Amount, 0.00) AS MaxAmountCreditable
FROM
  #balances AS B
  LEFT JOIN #AllocatedCredits AS AC ON B.BalanceID = AC.BalanceID
WHERE
  B.amount + COALESCE(AC.Amount, 0.00) > 0.00
GROUP BY
  B.client_id
```

You'll need to extend this last query to get the actual balance ID (cvtGuid, if I'm reading your table right) from that date, record these allocations in #AllocatedCredits, handle cases where the credit is enough to pay off multiple balances, etc.

Good luck, and don't hesitate to come back to SO if you need any help!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the #AllocatedCredits table and your last query? I have never used COALEACE before so I don't know what it does. I am not really understanding that last paragraph also.

Comment: Nevermind, I checked the MSDN and I understand what you are doing with COALESCE, but can you explain more on #AllocatedCredits and how you are applying them inside the loop?

Comment: When you have a match between a credit and a balance, you'll want to record it in another temp table w/ fields `BalanceID` and `CreditID`, and `AmountApplied`.  You would then deduct that amount applied from #credits.  When done, you would merge #balances w/ #AllocatedCredits to produce a new table, NetBalances.  Or you could skip the intermediate table and just update #balances, but my instinct is to track alloc. credits separately - f/ debugging if nothing else.  There's not really space f/ more detail here, but e-mail me at j_onsh_altz@gmail.com (w/o the _s) and I'll send more details.

Answer (score 2):

First, as you state, you should only be dealing with those clients that have balances.
Second, you can simulate a cursors functionality with a WHILE loop ..

here are the modifications to the code.  I left outer the guts of the calculations as they are not the issue... if you would like me to complete the code, let me know

```
--first, only deal with those clients with balances
select CLIENT_ID into #ToDoList 
from [IDAT_AR_BALANCES]
group by CLIENT_ID
having sum(amount)!=0

--next, get the temp debit and credit tables just for the clients you are working on
select * into #balances from [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] where amount > 0 and CLIENT_ID IN (SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM #ToDoList)
select * into #credits from [IDAT_AR_BALANCES] where amount < 0 and CLIENT_ID IN (SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM #ToDoList)

--fine
create index ba_ID on #balances (CLIENT_ID)
create index cr_ID on #credits (CLIENT_ID)

--simulate a cursor... but much less resource intensive

declare @client_id varchar(11)

-- now loop through each client and perform their aging
while exists (select * from #ToDoList)
begin
    select top 1 @client_id = CLIENT_ID from #ToDoList 

    --perform your debit to credit matching and account aging here, per client

    delete from #TodoList where Client_ID=@client_ID
end

--clean up.. drop temp tables, etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to verify if it would be faster but this is done with (mostly) set based operations instead of cursor based.

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @IDAT_AR_BALANCES TABLE (
  client_id INTEGER
  , amount FLOAT
  , date DATE
) 

INSERT INTO @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  SELECT 1, 20.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 30.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, -10.00, '1/3/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 5.00, '1/4/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 15.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, -40.00, '1/3/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 5.00, '1/4/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 10.00, '1/1/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, -20.00, '1/2/2011'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5.00, '1/3/2011'
```

**Delete all that adds up to 0 (90% of data)**

```
  DELETE FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES b
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT client_id
         FROM   @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
         GROUP BY 
                client_id
         HAVING SUM(amount) = 0
       ) bd ON bd.client_id = b.client_id
```

**Remaining records**

```
DECLARE @Oldest TABLE (
  client_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , date DATE
)

DECLARE @Negative TABLE (
  client_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , amount FLOAT
)  

WHILE EXISTS (  SELECT  b.client_id
                        , MIN(b.amount) 
                FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES b
                        INNER JOIN (
                          SELECT  client_id
                          FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
                          GROUP BY
                                  client_id
                          HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
                        ) r ON r.client_id = b.client_id                
                WHERE   b.amount < 0 
                GROUP BY 
                        b.client_id 
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
             )
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM @Oldest
  DELETE FROM @Negative

  INSERT INTO @Oldest
    SELECT  client_id
            , date = MIN(date)
    FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES 
    WHERE   amount > 0
    GROUP BY
            client_id

  INSERT INTO @Negative
    SELECT  b.client_id
            , amount = SUM(amount)
    FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES b
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Oldest o ON o.client_id = b.client_id AND o.date = b.date
    WHERE   amount < 0
            AND o.client_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY
            b.client_id

  UPDATE  @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  SET     b.amount = b.amount + n.amount
  FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES b
          INNER JOIN @Oldest o ON o.client_id = b.client_id AND o.date = b.date
          INNER JOIN @Negative n ON n.client_id = b.client_id

  DELETE FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
  FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES b
          LEFT OUTER JOIN @Oldest o ON o.client_id = b.client_id AND o.date = b.date
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  client_id
            FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
            GROUP BY
                    client_id
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
          ) r ON r.client_id = b.client_id
  WHERE   amount < 0
          AND o.client_id IS NULL

END  

DELETE  FROM @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
WHERE   amount = 0          

SELECT  *
FROM    @IDAT_AR_BALANCES
```

Comment: Your code gets stuck in a infinite loop, I think this is because you are not handling if there could be more than one credit balance remaining in the end.

Comment: @Scott - it works for the inputs you've provided. If you could change them to add a case that would cause this to go into an infinite loop, I'll be happy to look into it.

Comment: One other thing. When you say *90% of the time they cancel out each other* you might get a big performance boost by first deleting all client_id's with their sum being equal to 0 *before* executing your (or any) cursor based solution.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how i would write a query to do that, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Scott - sorry, I've been away. I have added the query to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One last thought...  I actually did write this very code for a large Pest Control CRM I developed a few years ago... and I found that the most effective solution for this problem was.... a .NET CLR Stored Proc.

While I usually avoid CLR Procs at all costs.. there ARE times when they outperform SQL.  In this case, procedural (row by row) queries with mathematical computations can be much faster in a CLR proc.

In my case, it was significantly faster than SQL.

FYI

Comment: I would really like to, but this solution needs to be distributed around easily. I do not want to create a stored procedure unless I REALLY need to. But that was one of my ideas too.

Comment: ya.. that makes sense... do take look at the code I posted above as it should solve your issue nicely.

Comment: Yep. CLR Can be useful for this type of thing. As a kind of extra fast cursor http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx